# Logic with dates pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am using Pyspark and I have data like this in the dataframe

[image]

and I want the output like this

[image]

The logic goes like this - from table 1 above,
the first date of category B for id=1 is 08/06/2022 and the first date for category A is 13/06/2022.So, for any dates on or after 13/06/2022 should have both categories A and B.
So, for 08/06/2022, there is category B only and for 13/06/2022 there is category A and B. For 24/06/2022, there is just category A in table1 but the output should have category B too as the first date of category B is 13/06/2022 and for 26/07/2022, there is just category B in table 1 but output should have both category and category B for 26/07/2022.

How do I achieve this in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# input dataframe creation    
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'cat', 'dt']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date'))

# required solution
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('min_dt', func.min('dt').over(wd.partitionBy('id'))). \
    withColumn('all_cats', func.collect_set('cat').over(wd.partitionBy('id'))). \
    withColumn('cat_arr', 
               func.when(func.col('min_dt') == func.col('dt'), func.array(func.col('cat'))).
               otherwise(func.col('all_cats'))
               ). \
    drop('cat', 'min_dt', 'all_cats'). \
    dropDuplicates(). \
    withColumn('cat', func.explode('cat_arr')). \
    drop('cat_arr'). \
    orderBy('id', 'dt', 'cat'). \
    show()

# +---+----------+---+
# |id |dt        |cat|
# +---+----------+---+
# |1  |2022-06-08|B  |
# |1  |2022-06-13|A  |
# |1  |2022-06-13|B  |
# |1  |2022-06-24|A  |
# |1  |2022-06-24|B  |
# +---+----------+---+
```

I've used a subset of the posted data. The idea of the approach is that you create an array of distinct categories and apply that to all dates except the minimum date. The minimum date will only have that row's category (not all categories). The array can then be exploded to get the desired result for all dates.

Comment: Hi @samkart,  thanks for you reply. I tried your code, but it's giving me 'data_ls' is not defined error.  How do I resolve that?

Comment: that part isn't required if you already have a dataframe. that piece creates a dataframe from a list of values with the column names provided

Comment: Ah, thanks @samkart, now it's giving me name 'func' is not defined.

Comment: `import pyspark.sql.functions as func` `from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd`

Comment: thanks @smakart. I am getting too many records for each id, a record for each date between minimun and maximum date. How do I achieve my desired output.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. would be good if you post the actual data scenario in the question.

Comment: Hi @samkart, it's the same data scenario as I mentioned in the question.  You created an array for all dates except the minimum date.  But it can also have 2 categories for the minimum date. How to generalise for all scenarios?

Comment: it'll still work. if there are multiple categories for the minimum date (within an id group) all categories will be retained (no records dropped or no extra records created for them)

Comment: Hi @samkart, please can you help with this as that's an extension of this question as I have deleted date now. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73740377/logic-with-dates-with-deleted-date-pyspark